# Why Internet Application not installed on emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created an android application which plays music from the Internet.

It is working properly when I run it from eclipse, but when I try to start the application from emulator by clicking icon on emulator, it shows a `Toast`, saying "Application is not installed on your phone".

I don't understand the reason. Can someone help me out?

```
07-27 18:40:17.543: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(537): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
07-27 18:40:17.543: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(537): CheckJNI is ON
07-27 18:40:19.543: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(537): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
07-27 18:40:19.683: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(537): Shutting down VM
07-27 18:40:19.703: INFO/AndroidRuntime(537): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #4' failed
07-27 18:40:19.715: DEBUG/dalvikvm(537): GC_CONCURRENT freed 100K, 72% free 296K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 2ms+4ms
07-27 18:40:19.715: DEBUG/jdwp(537): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
07-27 18:40:19.715: DEBUG/dalvikvm(537): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-27 18:40:20.283: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(548): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
07-27 18:40:20.283: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(548): CheckJNI is ON
07-27 18:40:21.193: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(548): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
07-27 18:40:21.233: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.nine.patch/.Patch } from pid 548
07-27 18:40:21.303: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(548): Shutting down VM
07-27 18:40:21.383: INFO/AndroidRuntime(548): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
07-27 18:40:21.799: DEBUG/dalvikvm(548): GC_CONCURRENT freed 102K, 69% free 319K/1024K, external 0K/0K, paused 1ms+2ms
07-27 18:40:21.799: DEBUG/jdwp(548): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
07-27 18:40:21.799: DEBUG/dalvikvm(548): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
07-27 18:40:22.583: DEBUG/dalvikvm(467): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4K, 53% free 2564K/5379K, external 2626K/3030K, paused 67ms
07-27 18:40:22.653: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(467): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
07-27 18:40:22.653: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(34): setDataSource('http://www.perlgurl.org/podcast/archives/podcasts/PerlgurlPromo.mp3')
07-27 18:40:22.664: INFO/NuHTTPDataSource(34): connect to www.perlgurl.org:80/podcast/archives/podcasts/PerlgurlPromo.mp3 @0
07-27 18:40:31.286: WARN/ActivityManager(61): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
07-27 18:40:31.356: WARN/ActivityManager(61): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{407f6138 com.nine.patch/.Patch}
07-27 18:40:31.706: DEBUG/AudioSink(34): bufferCount (4) is too small and increased to 12
07-27 18:40:32.073: INFO/ActivityManager(61): Displayed com.nine.patch/.Patch: +10s81ms
07-27 18:40:32.667: WARN/AudioFlinger(34): write blocked for 87 msecs, 1437 delayed writes, thread 0xc650
07-27 18:40:34.757: INFO/NuCachedSource2(34): ERROR_END_OF_STREAM
07-27 18:40:37.223: DEBUG/dalvikvm(140): GC_EXPLICIT freed 85K, 51% free 2950K/5959K, external 6050K/7443K, paused 81ms
07-27 18:40:37.696: WARN/AudioFlinger(34): write blocked for 72 msecs, 1493 delayed writes, thread 0xc650
07-27 18:40:42.715: WARN/AudioFlinger(34): write blocked for 71 msecs, 1557 delayed writes, thread 0xc650
07-27 18:40:47.728: WARN/AudioFlinger(34): write blocked for 71 msecs, 1620 delayed writes, thread 0xc650
07-27 18:40:52.731: WARN/AudioFlinger(34): write blocked for 71 msecs, 1684 delayed writes, thread 0xc650
07-27 18:40:57.752: WARN/AudioFlinger(34): write blocked for 71 msecs, 1748 delayed writes, thread 0xc650
07-27 18:41:02.791: WARN/AudioFlinger(34): write blocked for 73 msecs, 1809 delayed writes, thread 0xc650
07-27 18:41:07.803: WARN/AudioFlinger(34): write blocked for 75 msecs, 1874 delayed writes, thread 0xc650
07-27 18:41:11.637: ERROR/MP3Extractor(34): Unable to resync. Signalling end of stream.
```

That's the LogCat output.

Following is my Manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.nine.patch"
       android:installLocation="preferExternal"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET" android:debuggable="false">
        <activity android:name=".Patch"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: please those who has down voted the question can you please give the reasons also it will give me chance to improve thanx @Nitin

Comment: Are you getting any errors in LogCat during installation ?

Comment: when i firstly run programme it give error low memory space for installation but I change location with android:installLocation="preferExternal"then the error was removed

Comment: If you want I can also send you code and xml file

Comment: -1 for this bad formating. It's really not that hard to use the Editor-Tools.

Comment: Have you got an SD emulated on the emulator? Sounds like you should just create an fresh emulator image and start again

Comment: @Blundell sir I did it but it give the same output

Comment: I can't believe it gives the same output. Double check. So you created a new emulator, you attached an SD card to it. You installed your app. You hit home, you the went to your menu icon and it wouldn't load?

Comment: @Blundell sir It is also unbelievable for me My seniors also check this .Can I send you the code

Comment: Show us your manifest xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do - painful but should work - is to create another application, dead simple, which does next to nothing. That should install and work. Then start looking at every last difference between your working and non-working apps. Potentially including just moving all your code over to the new one.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen something like this happen when there was a desktop shortcut icon pointing to an old and no longer present version of the app.

Try trashing any desktop shortcuts and launching from the app drawer.

NOTE: this didn't work

Comment: Ah well.  One thing you can do - painful but should work - is to create another application, dead simple, which does next to nothing.  That should install and work.  Then start looking at every last difference between your working and non-working apps.  Potentially including just moving all your code over to the new one.

Comment: Thanks  sir now its working but I still do not know why it was behaving like that

Comment: Then you probably shouldn't accept this answer... I mean thanks and all, but it doesn't seem to be reliably informative.

Comment: But if sir the only solution was that then I should accept your answer

Comment: Well, if you really want to do it that way, I'll make the possibly useful comment into its own answer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1906/discussion-between-nitin-and-chris-stratton)